# How does command prompt connect to Internet? (In Window)

Tags: window

From command prompt, if we try,

```
git clone https://someServer.com/someRepo
```

How does it connect to https (ssl), hit the server and return the response? Similar question holds true for linux with pip install.

Comment: This is basically running an executable file, which can do anything. It's just not a visual executable, it's a console application.

Comment: I suspect basically when you download Git, it adds on symbols to the cmd list. And on writing git on the cmd, it looks for the git protocol files which runs the git executables. Looking into .git files might be useful.

Comment: @Phiter what do you mean by "It's just not a visual executable, it's a console application."?

Comment: I mean like, when you create a windows forms application, it runs in a window, you can see the interface, etc. Git, PHP, etc, those are also executables, but they don't have a user interface. They are just executables that run in the background and accept parameters. It's not exactly like a console application.

Comment: @Phiter thanks. It'll be interesting to learn how these executables are available in the background and get triggered with symbols on cmd.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ftp in cmd (type ftp and hit enter):

```
ftp>open mozilla.org
```

If you mean getting a response, type:

```
ping whateversyte.com
```